# Is there a cache type memory in Titanium I can use to persist data?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a simple app, and I added a tutorial with a few views with Labels and explanations, this was no problem, but I want it to run only once while the app is installed, or just when the user clicks the help sign.
is there a cache type memory on Appcelerator titanium that I could save it in both OS's ? 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties to store data

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('foo','bar');
var foo = Ti.App.Properties.getString('foo');
```

or you can save a file (txt,json)

Comment: the Ti.App.Properties solved my problem, since the app is simple and I did not want to use the txt file option, it solved my problem greatly and with a simple inbuilt feature, and this information vanishes when the app is uninstalled, exactly what I needed.